# Keep the total calculated percentage on top of Stacked bar chart - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-expression, ssrs-2017

I have data like below:

select  *   FROM  [SaleOfVeheicle]

```
            ID  Year        Month               Bike    Car      Bus
            -------------------------------------------------------------------
            1   2015        Jan                      12      11        1
            2   2015        Feb                      11      3         5
            3   2015        Mar                      12      12        12
            4   2016        jan                      12      23        4
            5   2016        feb                      5       23        1
            6   2016        Mar                      4       34        7
```

The idea is to show the Sale of Bike or Car or Bus as a Matrix report in SSRS 2017 and show the total percentage on top of the Stacked barchart.

Note: The targeted sale is 150.

I'm getting the Matrix report like this after writing below script:

```
            SELECT   [Year], 
               [Month], 
               Bike 
               FROM     [SaleOfVeheicle] 
               UNION 
           SELECT   'Total' as [Year], 
               [Month], 
               SUM(Bike) AS Bike 
                FROM     [SaleOfVeheicle] 
             GROUP BY [Month]
```

From SSRS:

[image]

[image]
[image: Preview]

In My “Series label Properties” , “Label Data” expression is as below:

```
            =IIF(Fields!Year.Value = "Total",Fields!Bike.Value,"")
```

Im My “Series Properties” ->“Fill”->”Pick color”-> “Color expression” is as below:

```
            =IIF(Fields!Year.Value="Total","Transparent","Automatic").
```

For Percentage calculation, below is my expression:
“Series Properties” -> “Configure Series data” -> “Value field”

```
            =(Sum(Fields!Bike.Value)/150)*100
```

### Edit

After adding an expression [series group properties label expression],

```
   =IIF(Fields!Year.Value = "Total"," ",Fields!Year.Value)
```

and

```
  =IIF(Fields!Year.Value = "Total",(Sum(Fields!Bike.Value)/150)*100,"")
```

getting my output Stacked bar chart as below:

[image]

What is expected:

1. ** it should show percentage, 2 decimal digit with % symbol.**

From note: The targeted sale is 150.

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve this?

Also, is there any quicker and easier way to do this in SSRS-2017?

Answer (score 0):

After using expression :

=IIF(Fields!Year.Value = "Total",Format((Sum(Fields!Bike.Value)/150)*100,"F2")+"%","")

[image]